# Write Dataframe into ODS format

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pyexcel

I am reading a **.xlxs** file using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) library and extracting the `dataframe`. Now I am trying to create a file with **.ods** extension and write the `dataframe` into it using [pyexcel_ods](https://github.com/pyexcel/pyexcel-ods) library.
Here is my code :--

```
import pandas as pd
from pyexcel_ods import save_data
from collections import OrderedDict

self.current_df = pd.read_excel('filename')
data = OrderedDict()
data.update(df)
save_data("as.ods", data)
```

It is throwing Error

> {TypeError}'int' object is not iterable

Feel free to ask for more code.

Note :-- I am using Python 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Soham try this, I think the issue with your solution is that the `save_data` function from py_ods is not getting the data in the format that it needs.

The explanation is in the comments.

```
# coding: utf-8

import pandas as pd
from pyexcel_ods import save_data
from collections import OrderedDict

def save_ods_from_excel(excel_file, target_ods_file):
    # First read into dataframe
    df = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
    # Change everything to string since we're just writing
    df = df.astype(str)
    # Initiliaze data to be written as an empty list, as pyods needs a list to write
    whole_data_list = []
    # Initiliaze the empty dict() for the data
    d = OrderedDict()
    # Write the columns first to be the first entries 
    whole_data_list.append(list(df.columns))
    # loop through data frame and update the data list
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        whole_data_list.append(list(row.values))
    # Populate dict() with updated data list
    d.update({"Moved sheet": whole_data_list})
    # Finally call save_data() from pyods to store the ods file
    save_data(target_ods_file, d)
```

Tried the above with [this data from microsoft](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=521962)

```
>>> save_ods_from_excel('/Users/gkm/Downloads/Financial Sample.xlsx', '/tmp/sample-financial.ods')
```

More info [the pyexcel ods docs](https://github.com/pyexcel/pyexcel-ods)

Comment: Thanks Man.Works perfectly,saved  my day.

Comment: Great, glad I could help

Answer (score 12):

Please note that in recent versions of Pandas (current is 1.1) has been implemented  support for ODS format in functions like [pd.ExcelWriter()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) and [pd.read_excel()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html). You only need to specify the propper engine "odf" to be able of working with OpenDocument file formats (.odf, .ods, .odt)

You will need the `odfpy` package installed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from pyexcel_ods import get_data 

current_df = pd.read_excel('array.xlsx')
data = OrderedDict()
data.update({ "Sheet_1": current_df.to_numpy().tolist() })
save_data("as.ods", data)

data = get_data("as.ods") 
data
#OrderedDict([('Sheet_1',
#             [['b', 121], ['c', 98], ['d', 9], ['e', 100], ['f', 45]])])
```

Comment: Getting same error -- TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable